# The teams feed sits on top of the stack overflow feed on the homepage, can we separate these?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, user-interface, front-page

Understandably, a lot of people in the Stack Overflow Teams, do not use Stack Overflow, so having the Teams feed on the bottom is not useful for them. But having Teams on the top is not useful for people who spend more time on Stack Overflow.

[image]

### Can we please separate these landing pages?

<sub>with whatever fancy smancy thing you want with the home buttons, if you must have them</sub>

[image]

[image]

### More importantly can we have the Stack Overflow button land on Stack Overflow?

[image]

### And these two links

[image]

It's a counter intuitive design trying to embed Teams on the front page like that. Yes, have a clear link to Stack Overflow Teams, but we're going into a separate area, as with jobs.

Comment: How about collapsing the team by default?

Comment: @LW001 or just having it on a separate page. Default collapsing can be frustrating

Answer (score 7):

Yes! I just joined a team, and now when I visit https://stackoverflow.com/, the page first displays questions from that team (about half a window height's worth), and only then the familiar content from Stack Overflow itself.

The first time it happened, I found this extremely confusing. I thought I'd landed on the wrong page — I wanted Stack Overflow but instead I seemed to have landed on Team X.

Now that I've seen what the page shows, I find it annoying. If I wanted Team X, I'd go to the Team X page. If I go to Stack Overflow, I want to see Stack Overflow.

I was about to post a [support](/questions/tagged/support) question asking where I can find the Stack Overflow front page now. But on second thoughts not having the Stack Overflow front page at https://stackoverflow.com/ is not only annoying, it's downright dangerous. I sometimes get mixed up when I switch sites (“oh, programming question, that's off-topic… wait no, I'm on SO, not on CS”), but this is a lot worse. There's a serious risk of seeing from the top of the page “oh, I'm on the private site”, clicking a question without noticing that it's in the public section, and posting an answer thinking that I'm posting it on the private site.

**Do not show private questions on https://stackoverflow.com/.**