# Redesigned sidebar appearing on Meta Stack Overflow

Tags: support, design, meta, sidebar, left-navigation

On June 5th, [the redesigned left-sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309349/351462) started appearing for me on Meta Stack Overflow.

[image: Meta Stack Overflow with sidebar]

The sidebar doesn't seem to be appearing on the main Stack Overflow site.

[image: Stack Overflow without sidebar]

I didn't see an announcement for this in the featured Meta posts or the SO blog.

Has Stack Exchange started rolling out the new sidebar? Or was this an unintentional change?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/check-out-the-sneak-peak-of-left-nav-new-theme-and-responsiveness, it should appear in the community bulletin soon (caching)

Comment: Shh, don't mention it and maybe they'll forget to turn it on for SO...

Comment: Maybe they thought *we* wouldn't notice?

Comment: @Script47 Ha, funniest thing I've ever heard.

Comment: tl;dr There is a check box to hide it under site preferences.

Comment: Pity, disabling it adds another hamburguer menu... [Questions] button now is two clicks away...

Comment: The benefit of this is what again? Other than change for the sake of change of course.

Comment: @j08691 That was covered in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes back in March - tl;dr they say a left nav is required with Teams layouts and they also want to combine their codebases so that non-Teams people see the same codebase but slightly tweaked.

Comment: @TylerH So this is all the fault of Teams? Got it.

Comment: Honestly this redesign is terrible. An important aspect in web design is content balance, and the left sidebar takes so much space that it clutters the entire design and shifted everything to the right.

Comment: This sidebar is utterly useless. I'm not saying it's terrible, but it's useless. It literally has no purpose and assists with nothing.

Comment: It looks weird and out of place, but I'll get used to it soon enough.

Comment: I am very happy with the sidebar! Yay!

Comment: @immibis completely agree. The top bar still exists, just now with a gap where the links used to be. All it's done is unbalance the central alignment.

Comment: left-nav broke all the styling on my page.

Comment: I like the hamburger opt out option in settings though.

Comment: The side bar is there if you are a member of the teams. It's awful https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368921/the-teams-feed-sits-on-top-of-the-stack-overflow-feed-on-the-homepage-can-we-se

Comment: It is very annoying!

Comment: Yay! a big column of whitespace sitting to the left of the window.  How about you add a row of say, 5cm of extra whitespace **between** answers to further remove the amount of content you can see at one time?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Posted an [announcement on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/check-out-the-sneak-peak-of-left-nav-new-theme-and-responsiveness) and we'd like to have feedback go there.

> **tl;dr**
>
> Today we are releasing an early sneak peak of work that has been in progress for several months on Meta Stack Overflow and later this week on Meta Stack Exchange. The motivation for this work is covered in my post entitled [Ch-ch-ch-changes: Left nav, responsive design, & themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes), so check that out if you have any questions about why this work is important.

Comment: It seems to be wasting a lot of space though. It is two times wider than it's content

Comment: @user000001 Well previously that space was just margin, so it's "wasting" space that is also wasted in the old layout.  That is, unless you're using a small window size (small enough that the main content can't fit at its max size); then it's *actually* wasting space.

Comment: @Servy: Yes, I often pin the browser to one side, so on the laptop 25% of the entire screen is the side panel https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4h8f.png

Comment: @user000001 So unpin the left nav via the new pref and I'm pretty sure that your 25% window scenario is actually better today than before. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Is it intentional that the search bar no longer expands when focused?

Comment: @JoeFriend: Thanks, really cool that you can unpin it, now it looks really good

Comment: @user000001 I applied a temporary Stylish fix for my tastes that works so long as the window is fullscreen at 1080px wide; a responsive fix to come later, for sure... http://i.stack.imgur.com/PZaQu.png

Comment: As a designer/developer, this is a terrible move. Anything this small is almost always horizontal (aka the way it was).

Comment: @jhpratt The current MSO is the most extreme version in terms of simplicity. With Teams and other features we are currently working on (see links in the MSE post) there will be the potential for much more in the left nav that could never have fit in the top bar. That's why we made the change. For example, here's [my SO.com left nav with teams](https://cl.ly/2Y2G3C0e3F1h/Image%202018-06-05%20at%206.52.52%20PM.png).

Comment: Sure, but for the majority of people that aren't on a team? It's just dead space, shifting the rest of the content to the right. At a minimum, make it sticky like the current header bar is.

Comment: @jhpratt The space won't be only used for Teams. I'd really encourage you to read the [first post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes) that lays out the background and the [follow up post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309349/left-nav-responsive-design-and-theming-next-steps) to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Servy: It depends entirely on the width of your browser window if that space was wasted margin in the old layout. For smaller windows the main content area is often smaller now.

Comment: The left-only vertical line all the way down feels so wrong to me...

Comment: @Servy Earlier The focus was on question, and answer, but now there is this sidebar which take some focus, in other words, it is at wrong place acc to me.

Comment: @JoeFriend Above ^.

Comment: @SurajJain Can you provide more context, maybe in the form of an answer/suggested improvement on this post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/check-out-the-sneak-peek-of-left-nav-new-theme-and-responsiveness

Comment: @JoeFriend I did https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311193/338436, This site was not ready for it. I do not think I can or anyone else can provide constructive criticism here.

Comment: @SurajJain I find that the posts below provide quite a bit of solid, constructive criticism. Yours was a fine opinion, but it didn't offer much in terms of a solution. And, if people don't agree with your point of view or proposed solution, then they will downvote it. That's how meta works.

Comment: @JoeFriend How was that not a solution hiding it when not needed. I will try to rephrase it and include some pictures too, once I make that script to hide it.

Comment: @SurajJain That would help. But you do know there is a preference to unpin the left nav, right?

Comment: @SurajJain Also, I would suggest that you delete many of your comments. They read as very defensive and probably don't help your case.

Comment: Registered users can opt-out. That's fine, but guest visitors have no option. I often browse SO (while logged out) on my tablet and I can tell you it's no pretty sight in portrait mode!

Answer (score -27):

This is good. I like this design. But It is better if you can make left sidebar as fixed sticky sidebar.

Comment: Seems like all others disagree with my idea. normally being sidebar fixed is really easy for me. So I don't want to  scroll again to find menu. Why others think it is too bad?

Comment: Maybe they disagree because [feedback should be posted on MSE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369065/4916627). And is it something like point 2 in [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310911/388562) there?

Comment: I doubt people are downvoting the sticky idea. They are downvoting because they don't like the left sidebar *at all*. If your statement was closer to "If we must have this, then at least make the selections in the sidebar always visible", then people wouldn't be downvoting as much.

Comment: @Makyen May be, but then how this post receive so many upvotes....

Comment: At +6/-23, perhaps some people are seeing past the first part to the sticky idea. Perhaps some people like the left sidebar. There isn't a good way to tell why people are voting the way they are. We can only guess.

Comment: it's meta, who cares.  personally though I don't even know what you're talking about, because isn't the sidebar already "fixed sticky"??

Comment: @sweaver2112 When I write the answer, it wasn't sticky. Seems like SO team care about what I and others request about sticky it.