# The Meta Stack Overflow "Ask Question" button has wrong coloring

Tags: bug, status-planned, design, asking-questions

It should be black, not outlined in *red*(?).

[image]

Comment: It is black to me https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFapi.png

Comment: Who says it should be black? Are the designers not allowed to change their minds and try different designs? This is likely `status-by-design`...

Comment: @NogShine that's another button, this post is about the button on the /questions page.

Comment: It depends on which page you are ... on [/questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions) it is still black.

Comment: @rene, yeah, it's [inconsistent right now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310914/2952320) but they're on it.

Comment: [Feedback is wanted on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369065/4916627)

Comment: [This was posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310914/388813) on the feedback question (likely due to this question) and was given `status-planned`

Comment: It feels like web designers get paid by the number of white pixels visible these days.

Answer (score 7):

This is part of the [new theme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310908/295232) which was announced on Meta Stack Exchange. Meta Stack Overflow will be the first site to have this:

> Today we are releasing an early sneak peek of work that has been in progress for several months on Meta Stack Overflow

so I'm sure it's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). It's [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)gy right now because it's still black on [other tabs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=hot) and the [/questions page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/):

[image]

Comment: Link to [your feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310914/388813)