# Search bar not expanding on meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, search-box

The sidebar is now [active for every user of MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/check-out-the-sneak-peek-of-left-nav-new-theme-and-responsiveness).

But I have a question: **Why is the search bar not full-sized when it is focused?**

[image: NO RED FHC]

It is on main:

[image: NO RED FHC]

<sub>Sorry, but I can't insert red free hand circles now. If you can do so, please edit my post</sub>

Comment: well it's just larger by default.  They've removed the questions, users, etc links. from the top bar *at all times* (and placed them elsewhere), rather than just removing them when the search bar has focus.

Comment: @Servy the problem is, **it is not larger**, it has nearly the same size as on main.

Comment: The width on main is 232 pixels, the width on MSO is 352 pixels.

Comment: @Servy it are 289 (main) and 318 (meta) for me, not this kind of big deal. It could span the whole page, but it does not

Comment: [Feedback is wanted on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369065/4916627)

Comment: @AndréKool oh, sorry didn't read this. Will do better next time.