# New meta sidebar layout change looks weird

Tags: bug

The new meta sidebar layout change looks weird , I saw it was [updated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369063/redesigned-sidebar-appearing-on-meta-stack-overflow) lately,

But there's too much space to the left.

I'm using Windows 7 with Chrome browser

Can this side bar be removed/changed?

[image]

Comment: @SebastianProske should I post an bug/change request as an answer there?

Comment: also note that Joe Friend indicated in their answer they prefer the feedback on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/check-out-the-sneak-peek-of-left-nav-new-theme-and-responsiveness so if you have an MSE account I think they appreciate if it is posted there. Accounts are free anyway  ...

Comment: @user7294900 as the accepted answer states: Posted an [announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/check-out-the-sneak-peek-of-left-nav-new-theme-and-responsiveness?cb=1) on MSE and we'd like to have feedback go there.

Comment: The sidebar can be removed by going to your [settings](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current) and checking _Hide Left Navigation_