# Addressing issues of the top navigation bar that magically turned to side navigation bar in SO meta

Tags: discussion, design

I don't know if SO is doing some testing but I am seeing a new SO meta view with a left navigation bar. I am finding it little overwhelming and want SO team to checkout the red areas of the screenshot.

**This question addresses the possible issues being faced due to new design and is not the duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369063/redesigned-sidebar-appearing-on-meta-stack-overflow) question**

<s>Till now it was only Top Nav bar that remained locked but now there is annoyingly sticky left nav bar as well that will stay on forever</s> (It can configured to be hidden from Settings) While left side is significantly empty, the right side is flooded with content, and the main central part has lost its width and is now making things little clumsier.

Also I felt the size of left nav bar to be much bigger than the content inside it. So just dropping this note for design team out there.

[image: Image 1]

On scrolling down, the controls of side nav bar goes up, and I had to scroll up again for navigation. The scrolling should be in the central portion and side nav bar should stay fixed; if at all it is meant actually for navigation.

[image: Image 2]

The view gets alienated much more for non-logged in users. They are seeing something like this. Here it is strange that a menu bar is being shifted for a banner! Usually a navigation bar controls stays fixed and the banner should be in the central content. Closing the banner makes the view proper again.

[image: Image 3]

Comment: You can hide the left navigation. See this post for instructions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369106/how-do-i-hide-the-left-navigation-sidebar

Comment: The question addresses the issues being faced due to design change and therefore it's not duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: The linked duplicate's answer says they want those issues addressed on [meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310908), so the answer to that question answers this one.